# How to compose git log for pending changes in TeamCIty

Tags: git, github, teamcity, commit

I have a TeamCity agent configured to build my XCode projects and I use github. I would like to automatically include in my release notes the descriptions from all pending commits in TeamCity.

How can I fetch them from github and store them in teamcity? Once I put them in a teamcity variable I can easily add them to my build script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "[Adding or Changing a Build Parameter from a Build Step](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-AddingorChangingaBuildParameterfromaBuildStep)" feature in order to update some build parameters right from a build step.

You would need a step which would call `git log origin/master..master` (see "[git: list commits not pushed to the origin yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080509/git-list-commits-not-pushed-to-the-origin-yet)"), after fetching from GitHub.
(See "[Using Team City With Git](http://devlicio.us/blogs/mike_nichols/archive/2010/06/12/using-team-city-with-git.aspx) " for the TeamCity configuration with GitHub, and make sure your [TeamCity is runnig with the right account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203436/how-to-set-git-commit-author-properly-from-rake-running-under-localsystem-acco))

Comment: Thanks,All my changes are pushed to github already, so the git log origin/master..master will not work, but I still see those changes and teamcity must track them somehow, just not sure how.

Answer (score 22):

THis is how I ended up doing this using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

curl -o lastBuild.tmp "http://localhost:8111/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt2/builds/status:SUCCESS" --user rest:rest
last_commit=`xpath lastBuild.tmp  '/build/revisions/revision/@version'| awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'`

echo "##Last commit = $last_commit"
# prepare build notes
NOTES=`git log --pretty=format:"- %s" $last_commit..origin/master`

echo "this is it:$NOTES"
```

Some explanations:

1. Use `curl` to fetch the last successful build from your build configuration. In my sample this is bt2, make sure to replace it with yours
2. Use XPath/AWK to parse the XML response and get the last git version
3. Use `git log` to get all changes form last build and format them anyway you want. I wanted to just get the commit descriptions.

Comment: How can you use the value of $NOTES in TeamCity?

Comment: Is there anyway to get any information on the revision from team city?

Comment: thanks for sharing this ! I had a little trouble setting it up with a different branch than the default one but I needed to add: `builds/status:SUCCESS,branch:other_branch`

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of issues when I implemented the above answer, which are updated here:

```
#!/bin/bash 

curl -o lastBuild.tmp "http://localhost:8111/app/rest/buildTypes/id:%system.teamcity.buildType.id%/builds/status:SUCCESS" --user rest:rest
last_commit=`xpath lastBuild.tmp '/build/revisions/revision/@version'| awk -F"\"" '{print $2}'`

git log --pretty=format:"- %%s" $last_commit..origin/master > changes.txt
```

Some more detailed things:

1. Use `curl` to fetch the last successful build from your build configuration. You can use teamcity's substitution to put in the build id.
2. Note that the curl command relies on having a TeamCity user called rest, with a password "rest".  Suggest changing the password.
3. Use XPath/AWK to parse the XML response and get the last git version
4. Use `git log` to get all changes form last build and format them anyway you want. I wanted to just get the commit descriptions and write them to a file.  You'll need to make sure the file goes away between builds by setting up git to clean in-between.  NB: If you're building off of anything other than master, you'll need the right branch spec here.
5. Note that the `git log` format option uses %, which is the teamcity substitution marker, and thus needs to be escaped as %%.
6. You need to do configure TeamCity to make the .git directory accessible.  See [Using git commands in a TeamCity Build Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632624/using-git-commands-in-a-teamcity-build-step)
7. The changes are now in the changes.txt file.  In my application (editor improving question) I used this file to submit to crashlytics for an iOS beta distribution.