# How do I get TeamCity to create the .git directory when cloning a repo for build?

Tags: git, msbuild, teamcity

I'm trying to run a custom command in my MSBuild file; it basically runs 'git log -10' and stores that commit info into a text file.

The problem is, when I try to run the build, it errors saying "fatal: Not a git repository".  So I checked TeamCity's work directory for my project, and there is no .git directory!

Why doesn't TeamCity create the .git directory when it clones the repository?  Is there a way to enable this?

edit: TeamCity version is 7.1.2; I'll try updating to 8.0.1 to see if there is an option available for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using git commands in a TeamCity Build Step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632624/using-git-commands-in-a-teamcity-build-step)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I changed the VCS checkout mode from server to "automatically on agent" and it works now! Thanks to the answer for this question: [Using git commands in a TeamCity Build Step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632624/using-git-commands-in-a-teamcity-build-step).

Comment: Unfortunately it wont let you do this if you have checkout rules :-(

Answer (score 5):

It is documented as VCS Checkout Mode:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/VCS+Checkout+Mode

TeamCity version is 9.x

Comment: Default changed in 10.x but old settings are retained when upgrading: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Checkout+Mode