# How to set up SSH authenticated git commands in a TeamCity build step

Tags: git, ssh, teamcity, ssh-keys, teamcity-9.0

I need to execute git commands in a TeamCity build step.

These git commands need to use a SSH-based url for the git repo in order to authenticate as a priviliged user to the git server (because these git commands will actually modify the git repo, not just read it).

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632624/using-git-commands-in-a-teamcity-build-step).

I have already VCS checkout mode "Automatically on Agent". The VCS root is correctly configured with ssh and working well.

However, as [stated in the documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/SSH+Keys+Management), TeamCity

> temporarily saves the key on the agent's file system and removes it after git fetch/clone is completed.

So even though the TeamCity correctly used the SSH key during agent-side checkout, the key is intentionally not accessible later in the build.

But I really want to use the key later!

The output that the git commands generate is:

```
[06:12:29][Step 3/4] Permission denied (publickey).
[06:12:29][Step 3/4] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[06:12:29][Step 3/4] 
[06:12:29][Step 3/4] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[06:12:29][Step 3/4] and the repository exists.
```

I have confirmed that the `known_hosts` file exists and contains the appropriate public keys. I have also confirmed that the `C:\Users\systeamcityagent\.ssh` does not contain any private keys (as expected).

I am running TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.3.

What is the recommended solution for this?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am in a similar situation and I am having a hard time getting the ssh agent to work with my git push.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Teamcity 9.1 introduced a new Features called SSH Agent that allows you to establish Agent side SSH Connections using Server Stored SSH Keys:

[image]

See [What´s New in TeamCity 9.1](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/What's+New+in+TeamCity+9.1#What'sNewinTeamCity9.1-SSHAgent)

Comment: Can you expand on how the agent or key is used in the command line. I am still having a hard time getting this to work.

Comment: Check the [official docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/SSH+Keys+Management), it´s very well explained there. You´ll need some basic understanding of SSH  Keys but that´s about it.

Comment: oh, this really saved my @55 from trying to re-invent the wheel.